# Parsing "12:00" to Time in java

Tags: java, sql, time

I am using this method to parse a String to SQL Time in Java. However, it does not work relly good due to the fact it return a date with a negative value when I input "12:00".

Here is the method:

```
public static Time isoStringToTime(String isoTimeString) {
        try {
            
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        return new Time(sdf.parse(isoTimeString).getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Formato ISO incorrecto para fecha: " + isoTimeString);
        }
    }
```

The new Time returned introducing "12:00" has a negative value, -3600000 is the value.

Comment: `HH:mm` is the pattern you are looking for

Comment: Yeah sorry in eclipse I have it in that format

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/m2gtBG

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe and you should prefer using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` in new code.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Time`. `SimpleDateForamt` is notoriously troublesome, `Time` is a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date`  class, and both (and all three) are long outdated. Instead just use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @shmosel Parsing 12:00 into 00:00 — do you call that “works”?

Comment: @OleV.V. I assume it's defaulting to am. If OP is looking for 24-hour time, `HH:mm` works fine too, as @jmj suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "12:00" )
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `java.sql.Time`, `Date`, `Calendar`, or `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "12:00" ) ;
```

To catch faulty input, trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

```
LocalTime lt = null ;
try {
    lt = LocalTime.parse( "12:00" ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … // Handle faulty input.
}
```

Submit to a database, with a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , lt ) ;
```

Retrieve from a database.

```
LocalTime lt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! That methods were given my teachers at the university, I guess they are not so up-to-dated :)

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezSuárez That is sad. The *java.time* classes arrived in [Java 8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8) back in the year 2014, seven years ago. And Java 8 was a big deal, the first Long-Term Support (LTS) version.

Comment: Those classes were deprecated in Java 1.1 in 1997.

Comment: @MarlinPierce No, the classes were not deprecated, only many of their methods.